# IF conditions in rails is not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr

I'm trying to do solr search based on the text entered by the user. Firts I've to check whether the entered text is store or brand or category. After checking that condition I want to display corresponding riesults which are in the MainNavigationUrls table using solr search. Here is the controller action. It is working fine if I enter any store and can get proper results. But it is not going inside brands loop if the storesearch is found nill. Please explain why it is not executing the second case.

```
def search_all
    @storesearch=Site.search do
      fulltext params[:text]
      with(:multibrand,1)
    end

    if(@storesearch.nil?)
      @brandsearch=Brand.search do
        fulltext params[:text]
      end
      if(@brandssearch.nil?)
        @itemcategorysearch=MainCategory.search do
          fulltext params[:text]
        end
        @itemcategorysearch.results.each do |result|
          @itemcategorysearch1=MainNavigationUrl.search do
            with :main_categoty_id, result.id
            with :department_id, params[:deptid].to_i
            paginate :page=>params[:page], :per_page=>45
          end
        end
      else
        @brandsearch.results.each do |result|
          @brandsearch1=MainNavigationUrl.search do
            with :brand_id, result.id
            with :department_id, params[:deptid].to_i
            paginate :page=>params[:page], :per_page=>45  
          end
        end

    else
      @storesearch.results.each do |result|
        @storesearch1=MainNavigationUrl.search do
          with :site_id, result.id
          with :department_id, params[:deptid].to_i
          paginate :page=>params[:page], :per_page=>45
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of .nil? ,maybe you can use .blank? is better?

```
@array = []
@array.nil? -false
@array.blank?  -true
```

I think you are checking if @storesearch contain some elements?

Comment: I got the answer... I just replaced if(@storesearch.nil?) with if (@storesearch.results.empty?)...... Thanks for your support.... :)